c# .net 8 Lambda Minimal API deployment is failing when pushing to AWS
I have a .net visual studio 2022 aws lambda minimal api project which I can successfully run locally but when I try to use the "publish to AWS Lambda" action in the solution explorer it fails and roles back.
I assume the issue is in my serverless.template but I have tried to fix it with the help of copilot but it was confused and generating the wrong information.
I am ideally trying to deploy my lambda up and implement a api gateway with http api and not rest api.
Can anyone confirm that the json is correct as I have checked and the host is my assembly/namespace.
{ "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "Admin API for USERS",
    "Resources": {
        "HttpApi": {
            "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
            "Properties": {
                "StageName": "Prod",
                "BinaryMediaTypes": [
                    "*~1*"
                ],
                "Cors": {
                    "AllowHeaders": [
                        "'Content-Type'",
                        "'Authorization'",
                        "'X-Amz-Date'",
                        "'X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                    ],
                    "AllowMethods": [
                        "'GET'",
                        "'POST'",
                        "'PUT'",
                        "'PATCH'",
                        "'DELETE'",
                        "'OPTIONS'"
                    ],
                    "AllowOrigin": "'*'"
                }
            }
        },
        "AdminUsers": {
            "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Handler": "Project.Lambda.Admin.Users",
                "Runtime": "dotnet8",
                "CodeUri": "",
                "MemorySize": 512,
                "Timeout": 30,
                "Role": "arn:aws:iam::{text}:role/Lambda-Role",
                "Policies": [
                    "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
                ],
                "Events": {
                    "ProxyResource": {
                        "Type": "HttpApi",
                        "Properties": {
                            "Path": "/{proxy+}",
                            "Method": "ANY"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "ApiURL": {
            "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
            "Value": "https://${HttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
        }
    }
}

The error I got from cloudformation is
29/05/2024 19:18:37    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Admin   arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:495529815090:stack/Admin/7ab221c0-1de7-11ef-ab19-0ab4151e74f3      The following resource(s) failed to create: [AdminUsers, HttpApiDeployment6dcf956786]. Rollback requested by user. 
I have tried the original version which generated a Rest API which is not what I want and I have tried multiple version of the json to try and get this working and I am lead to believe that the version I have now is correct.

Oh, so you want to replace the REST API present in original template with the HTTP API. Right?

yes I have assumed that my serverless.template is now configured for httpapi but the error makes me doubt it and aws cloud formation rolls it all back.

Can you refer the SAM template used in this pattern?
https://serverlessland.com/patterns/apigw-http-api-lambda-dotnet-sam
